# C# CrossThreadMessaging on reading label text

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have seen innumerous topics but all of them talk about updating the `text` value of a control **not** retrieving the value of it.

I currently use the following function to avoid `cross thread operations` and works fine when calling functions or assigning values.

```
private void ExecuteSecure(Action a)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        BeginInvoke(a);
    else
        a();
}
```

**So, what works**?

```
ExecuteSecure(() => this.label_options.Text = "Hello");
```

**What do you need**?

```
string value = string.Empty;
ExecuteSecure(() => value = this.label_options.Text);
```

It would be great to create a default function that would work like `ExecuteSecure()`.

**What error do you have**?

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException

This message appears when I move my cursor into the `.Text` value of `this.label_options`.

**EDIT 1**: 
The imagem below shows the error, although the code works.
[image]

Comment: Don't use `BeginInvoke` if you plan on using variable capture to get a result back.

Comment: @Servy: I'm curious...why did you rollback the OP's edits?

Comment: It's not a part of the question.  If the OP has an answer, he can post an answer.  He should not be editing the question.  Meta commentary on the votes of the question don't belong in the question.

Comment: I didn't write as an answer because I was not sure of the result. Besides, my first edit had nothing to do with the answer and it was also delete, but nevermind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest fix is to use `Invoke()` instead. It's synchronous (doesn't return until the invoked method returns) and so you can rely on it to set captured variable state.

One version of that is to simply modify your existing method to call `Invoke()` instead of `BeginInvoke()`. An alternative is to make a generic method that actually returns the value that a passed-in `Func<T>` returns:

```
private T getExecuteSecure<T>(Func<T> f)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        return (T)Invoke(f);
    else
        return f();
}
```

You could use that like this:

```
string value = getExecuteSecure(() => this.label_options.Text);
```

Note that similar to the above, it is also possible to receive the return value when using `BeginInvoke()`. But it's tricky, as you can only get it from a call to `EndInvoke()`, executed after you know that the invoked delegate has completed (which in turn you find out via the `IAsyncResult` returned from `BeginInvoke()`).

**EDIT:**

As for the exception you see in the debugger, this is because when VS evaluates a property, it actually runs the property getter in a thread. But that thread is not the correct thread for the property. Hence the exception.

Comment: The question is saying that he's getting a cross thread exception when moving the cursor over a textbox.  Whether the invoke is done synchronously or asynchronously wouldn't affect whether that exception is thrown, only whether or not the variable is populated.

Comment: Your answer actually works and I will accept it, but let me tell you two points: the first one is that changing to `Invoke(a)` (in my function) it starts working; the second point is that using your code works, the value is returned without any problem, but the "error" I told in my topic still persists.

Comment: @Servy: that's only part of his question. The core (IMHO) is the "What do you need?" section, which the above addresses. I will add a comment regarding the debugger behavior, in case that's actually important (I doubt it is, but whatever...)

Comment: It's entirely unclear what the actual problem is because his description of the problem is so contradictory.  Since he fails to both adequately describe the problem, and provide a reproducible example, the question, as it is, is effectively unanswerable.  You've pointed out a potential problem, and a potential fix, but apparently have not actually solved the problem that he has (which is unsurprising, because it's entirely clear what that problem actually is).

Comment: @Linesofcode: please see my edit...the debugger's message is normal, as the debugger doesn't/can't hijack the UI thread that owns the control for the purpose of evaluating the property.

Comment: @PeterDuniho ok thank you. But your code was relevant otherwise I couldn't access the value of the `text`.

Comment: Note that this code move tail of your async code back to UI thread. Be very carefull in what you run there (i.e. "read value of textbox and run DB query" will freeze UI).